# Where does an ARM Linux store the current kernel SP while in user mode?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm

I have the following situation: a Linux OS (ARM) runs on a virtual platform, and a simple program is started within the OS with a breakpoint on a certain symbol. When this breakpoint is hit, we are in the user space.

My question is: **having a full overview of the entire virtual memory of the (currently running) process (i.e., kernel + user space)**, can I somehow find out the address of the `task_struct` or `thread_info` structures located on the (bottom) of the kernel stack? I'm aware that in the kernel mode it's possible to use a mask on the SP to get the bottom of the kernel stack but this won't work if the SP points to something in the user space. Essentially I'm trying to do something similar to the **current / current_thread_info()** macros in the kernel.

The reason I think this is hard / impossible is because the kernel stack address is randomized and thus changes with each new process.

**Things I need to avoid:**

1. system calls : the OS, kernel and process are 'frozen' and we have a static view of the memory
2. call any functions that require a running OS

Comment: Yeah, back to old DOS days where every process could wreck the system. Geez, I hope there is no way to do that!

Comment: Now ask about the real problem.

Comment: Maybe something with `/proc/self/task/` *`threadid`* `/maps`  It's not going to be fast, like the kernel macros.

Comment: I don't see how the misleading title relates to the question, which appears to be about debugging a stopped VM or emulated system - if you have 'external' debug access from the hypervisor/emulator level then you have a hell of a lot more power than "from user mode" implies - this needs clarification. That said, it must be possible to slurp all the current tasks and their stacks out of a live kernel on a stopped target, because the debugger I use has precisely that feature; I've never looked into the details of _how_ it manages that, though...

Comment: This boils down to: where does the ARM architecture save the current kernel SP for a task while in usermode.

Comment: @Olaf I mentioned this is a virtual environment where I actually have access to the kernel stack and all registers, all the time.

Comment: @EugeneSh. can't see how such answers help in any way.. there are some of us who once in a while can't ask a very specific question but still try to explain what they are looking for. See caf 's comment and answer.

Comment: @artless-noise no, it's the Synopsys' Virtual Prototype Analyzer. Trick is it let's you access the kernel space, you just need to know what you're searching for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To determine the supervisor mode SP while the target is in userspace, you need to examine the `R13_svc` register.

If you take this value and set the 13 least significant bits to zero, you should have the virtual address for the `struct thread_info` of the current thread.

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was looking for. Just to make sure: the saved SP in that register points to an address in the kernel stack of the currently running process, right? I'll verify it on Monday and mark it as accepted.

Comment: @zbarni: As far as I can tell, but having never actually done exactly what you're asking I'm interested to hear how it goes.

Comment: The address of the supervisor mode SP is indeed in `r13_svc` (what I needed), but the kernel space is unreachable with the core in `user mode` even on this virtual platform. However, changing the core to `system mode` (setting the mode bits) solved this.